# Cairolatex in arxiv

Tags: gnuplot, arxiv

If I use in gnuplot the cairolatex terminal, it will create a `foo.pdf` and a `foo.tex` file, where the pdf contains the plot without the text and the .tex file contains the text and includes the pdf file. Unfortunately, the `.pdf` is removed on the arXiv due to a "naming conflict", presumably because it sees that a `.tex` file is present.

Is there any way to either allow arXiv to either upload a .tex and a .pdf with the same name, or can I somehow generate via gnuplot two files with a different name? I'd like to avoid manually changing the name of the file as I would like to do it automatically in my robust-externalize library and tools like `sed` are not available in windows by default.

Comment: Would eps mode in cairolatex be an option?

Comment: Or maybe standalone mode if you prefer a pdf (see http://www.gnuplot.info/docs/loc19382.html for all the options)

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, standalone could maybe work, but my users might actually want to use the non-standalone mode to use the document font. And eps might have the same issue no? For now, I ended up writting a script to rename all `.tex` into `.tex-backup`, and when I load my library, I write back the `.tex-backup` into `.tex`… it works at least quite reliably and in all circumstances.

Comment: I didn't test it, but I would be surprised if arXiv would delete an eps file because there is a tex file with the same name.